# Setting the background in an MVC _Layout.cshtml page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url, razor, background-image

Setting every page's background is rather simple in ASP.Net WebForms where you have access to the Page_Load event in the code-behind of a MasterPage but how is this best done in MVC? After spending several hours researching various alternatives I chose to assign the value to the ViewBag through a "base" controller, derive subsequent controllers from that base and then access that value in _Layout.cshtml.

Here is the base controller, in which I assign a url that points to a specific image:

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    public BaseController()
    {
        ViewBag.url = BingImageLoader.getBingImageUrl();    
    }
}
```

The next step is to derive subsequent controllers, in this case the HomeController from that base class:

```
public class HomeController : BaseController
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
    .
    .
```

And finally, use the ViewBag in the head element of _Layout.cshtml to set the background-image style property.

```
    .
    .   
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            background-image: url(@ViewBag.url);  
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-size: cover;
        }
    </style>
</head>
```

This did accomplish what I set out to do; however, along the way there were a number of alternatives indicated, including using ActionFilters. To be honest, creating a CustomActionFilter and using ActionFilterAttributes and overriding OnActionExecuting seems like overkill but sometimes the simplest way is not always the best.

Ultimately, the question comes down to "Is there a better way?" Are there side-effects from introducing an intermediary? If I override my ViewBag.url in the individual controller methods, the image changes accordingly. So I have yet to find any problems but there may be other issues resulting from this approach.

So again, "Is there a better way"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible problem I can see with this approach is if the developer forgets to subclass hist controller from `BaseController`.

Using a [`global action filter`](http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/asp-net-mvc-3-global-action-filters) would ensure that this will never happen and the property will be always available:

```
public class BackgroundImageFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        context.Controller.ViewBag.url = BingImageLoader.getBingImageUrl();
    }
}
```

which will be registered only once in your `Application_Start`:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    ...
    // Register global filter
    GlobalFilters.Filters.Add(new BackgroundImageFilterAttribute());
}
```

If you find this filter approach cumbersome as an alternative I can suggest writing a custom Html helper that could be used in your `_Layout.cshtml`:

```
<style type="text/css">
    body {
        background-image: url(@Html.GetBackgroundImageUrl());
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
    }
</style>
```

which might be defined as a simple extension method:

```
public static class HtmlExtensions
{
    public static IHtmlString GetBackgroundImageUrl(this HtmlHelper html)
    {
        string url = BingImageLoader.getBingImageUrl();
        return new HtmlString(url);
    }
}
```

Comment: Both the action filter and the extension method work equally well and alleviate the need to subclass. As shown above, overriding OnActionExecuted will set the background

Comment: OnActionExecuted will set the background for all pages for every controller, while for my immediate purpose overriding OnActionExecuting proves a better choice by still allowing me to assign the ViewBag.url in any controller method. Strangely, both overrides work for me without attaching any attribute to the controller or method.   In the case of the HtmlExtensions, I find them far more awkward when trying to change the background. For my requirements the ActionFilter appears to be the best option. Thanks Darin.

Comment: hi, how do I sue this and set the target background to the current div (partialview vs view vs full _Layout)